# Can I change LIO SCSI Disk Vendor name

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scsi, iscsi

I'm using LIO for SAN scsi. 
The shared disks shown as LIO-ORG at client side.

Example;

```
[root@testing ~]# lsblk -S
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
sdc  4:0:0:0    disk LIO-ORG  mydisk         4.0  fc
```

I can change the VENDOR name if I build my own kernel but it's not sustainable.
So the question is can I change the Vendor name with any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a mail to target-devel maillist and thanks to "David Disseldorp" I got an answer from him.

> This functionality was added recently via:
>   https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=54a6f3f6a43cf5a5ad0421e4440a4c7095e7a223
>
> With this change (and 2d882847280e3ae1ddc95175d0fc2006e11bb63f), you
>   can change the vendor ID via the configfs path at:
>   target/core/$backstore/$name/wwn/vendor_id

So excluding distributions with backports, you'll need a kernel >= v5.0.